# Accessing UI Objects During Filestream c#

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar, task, backgroundworker

I have code as follows:

```
private void btnCovert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get file
    string blfrpath = txtPath.Text;
    byte[] b = new byte[108];
    //ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string blfObjstr;
    long filesize;
    long numObjs;
    int i;

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(blfrpath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        filesize = fs.Length;
        numObjs = filesize / 56;
        i = 0;
        while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
        {
            blfObjstr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
            lstData.Items.Add(blfObjstr);
            prbConvert.Value = (i/(int)numObjs)*100;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

trouble is when the button is clicked rather than the list box being updated every iteration or the progress bar increasing the form seems to freeze and appear to crash during the whole ~30seconds it takes to run. How can I prevent this ?

I have tried using task, adding this to the end (and making the click event async)

```
            Task<int> task = updateUI(blfObjstr, i, (int)numObjs);
            int result = await task; 
        }

}

private async Task<int> updateUI(string listStr, int probNum,int prbDenom)
{
    prbConvert.Value = (probNum/prbDenom) * 100;
    lstData.Items.Add(listStr);
    return 1;
}
```

I have tried adding a background worker both just a simple one: with the update stuff in a background worker. but I just get "this background worker is already busy" on the second iteration, even when I put i as an argument when I run it.

I have tried putting the whole thing in a background editor and then doing the update in a report progress call but that doesn't work either.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using main UI thread for long computation. UI thread is responsible for updating UI, so if you block it with long computation your app will freeze.
Setting property like prbConvert.Value doesn't directly update UI it just generate message for UI thread to update UI later.

You can do file read on different thread using task:

```
private async void btnCovert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get file
    string blfrpath = txtPath.Text;
    byte[] b = new byte[108];
    //ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string blfObjstr;
    long filesize;
    long numObjs;
    int i;

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(blfrpath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        filesize = fs.Length;
        numObjs = filesize / 56;
        i = 0;
        while (await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(fs.BeginRead, fs.EndRead, b, 0, b.Length, null) > 0)
        {
            blfObjstr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
            lstData.Items.Add(blfObjstr);
            prbConvert.Value = (i/(int)numObjs)*100;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

There are more ways how this can be solved this is just one of them, other could be BackgroundWorker class or use own Thread and do Invoke to update UI.